# React props comparison: "_.isEqual" versus "==="

Tags: reactjs, properties, react-redux, lodash, equality

My issue is that lodash's deep comparison of equality and ==='s strict equality return different values when comparing fields of nextProps and self.props in the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method.

1. Does this mean that the values of these properties must be of different types? I'm assuming _.isEqual does do type conversion to compare equality since === does not.
2. Is it recommended to use _.isEqual when doing equality checking between fields of nextProps and self.props?

Here's my specific example -

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  (nextProps.obj === self.props.obj);        // false
   _.isEqual(nextProps.obj, self.props.obj); // true

   typeof(nextProps.obj);  // object
   typeof(self.props.obj); // object

   nextProps.obj;   // { k1: "v1", k2: "v2", k3: "v3" }
   self.props.obj;  // { k1: "v1", k2: "v2", k3: "v3" }
}
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 15):

**_.isEquals** :

Performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent. it will return true if the values are equivalent, else false.

[Lodash _.isEquals](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual)

Example:

```js
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };
 
console.log(_.isEqual(object, other));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**===** :

For strict equality the objects being compared must have the same type and:

> compared must have the same type and:
>
> - Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of
>     characters, same length, and same
>     characters in corresponding positions.
> - Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have
>     the same number value). NaN is not
>     equal to anything, including NaN.
>     Positive and negative zeros are equal
>     to one another.
> - Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or
>     both are false.
> - Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object

[Comparison Operators - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Example:

```js
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };
 
 
console.log(object === other);
// => false
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when you use '===' to compare objects then it will only return true if it is the same object whereas _.isEqual will return true if the object are equivalent.

With reference to your actual question, I think you should use _.isEqual to compare 2 objects to see if they are the exact copy of each other.

For details see:
https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Answer (score 0):

React components have very heavy keys. When comparing properties, it doesn't make sense to compare these keys because they don't contain application state data. In addition, there is a danger of falling into the circular references trap, which will lead to an endless cycle of validating the properties of the React component. For this reason, these properties are best ignored. This trick is used in the [epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal](https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal/blob/master/src/index.jst) library.

```
const isPropsEqual = _.isEqualWith(
      data1,
      data2,
      (data1Value, data2Value, key) => {
        const ignoreKeysList = [
          '_owner',
          '$$typeof'
        ]
        return ignoreKeysList.includes(key) ? true : undefined
      }
    )
```

It's just a workground that helps you ignore the structural parts of a React component when comparing.